# Json.NET - Custom Converter - String To Int

Tags: c#, json.net

I've got a problem regarding Json.NET and the omdbapi. I'm trying to retrieve information from the omdbapi and some properties are giving me headaches, particularly the "imdbVotes" one since it's written, in example, as "321,364" so I can't get an integer from it.

I'm betting that I need a custom converter, but I'm afraid that, at the moment, I don't really understand how to create one for my particular problem.

All other properties work well (I'm not using all of them at the moment).

This is the response for, lets say Snatch : http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=&t=snatch

This is my class :

```
public class MovieJSON
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Title")]
    public String Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Year")]
    public int Year { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Genre")]
    public String Genre { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Director")]
    public String Director { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Actors")]
    public String Actors { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Plot")]
    public String Plot { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Poster")]
    public String Poster { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Metascore")]
    public int Metascore { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "imdbRating")]
    public decimal ImdbRating { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "imdbVotes")]
    public int ImdbVotes { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE #1 :**

How can I handle the response when the property has the value "N/A"?. That happens for some movies (ie. http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=&t=four+rooms has it's Metascore set to N/A).

**UPDATE #2 :**

Another related inquiry. I'm using EF6 with MySQL and the idea's to populate the database with movies created through JSON parsing.

This is my Movie class :

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
[Table("movies")]
public class MovieJSON
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Title")]
    [Column("title")]
    public String Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Year")]
    [Column("year")]
    public int Year { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Genre")]
    [Column("genre")]
    public String Genre { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Director")]
    [Column("director")]
    public String Director { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Actors")]
    [Column("actors")]
    public String Actors { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Plot")]
    [Column("plot")]
    public String Plot { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Poster")]
    [Column("poster")]
    public String Poster { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Metascore")]
    public String Metascore { get; set; }

    [Column("metascore")]
    public int MetascoreInt
    {
        get
        {
            int result;
            if (int.TryParse(Metascore, NumberStyles.AllowThousands, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out result))
                return result;
            return 0;
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "imdbRating")]
    public String ImdbRating { get; set; }

    [Column("imdb_rating")]
    public Decimal ImdbRatingDecimal
    {
        get
        {
            Decimal result;
            if (Decimal.TryParse(ImdbRating, out result))
                return result;
            return 0;
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "imdbVotes")]
    public String ImdbVotes { get; set; }

    [Column("imdb_votes")]
    public long ImdbVotesLong
    {
        get
        {
            long result;
            String stringToParse = ImdbVotes.Remove(ImdbVotes.IndexOf(','), 1);

            if (long.TryParse(stringToParse, out result))
                return result;
            return 0;
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "imdbID")]
    [Column("imdb_id")]
    public String ImdbID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "type")]
    [Column("type")]
    public String Type { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        String[] propertiesToIgnore = {"MetascoreInt", "ImdbRatingDecimal", "ImdbVotesLong"};
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        PropertyInfo[] properties = GetType().GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in properties)
        {
            if (propertiesToIgnore.Contains(propertyInfo.Name))
                continue;

            sb.AppendLine(String.Format("{0} : {1} ",
                propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.GetValue(this, null)));
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

This is my EF6 configuration-context class (I'm ignoring the String fields and instead, using the Helper ones since the database is configured to accept int for Metascore and so on) :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MovieJSON>().Ignore(e => e.Metascore).Ignore(e => e.ImdbRating).Ignore(e => e.ImdbVotes);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Additional image info :

Object values before insertion into the database (all values are properly set)

[Valid XHTML http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/689/8x5m.png](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/689/8x5m.png)

Values in the database :

[Valid XHTML http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/844/nvc5.png](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/844/nvc5.png)

The helper fields (MetascoreInt, ImdbRatingDecimal, ImdbVotesLong) are returning zero, I can't figure out why.

Any help would be mucho appreciated! :)

All the best

Comment: One way to do it would be to accept `ImdbVotes` as a string, and then parse it later. Stripping unwanted characters from a string is [easy enough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/844skk0h(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've replied to the bottom comment, the suggested solution's the same :).

Comment: @D6mi `N/A` is just a string u can do the same thing ;)

Comment: @D6mi sorry i might missed it but are u using winforms or WPF(with binding)

Comment: @Jim Alrighty. Thanks a bunch! :)
Btw, just for learning, could I've done this via Custom Converters for a slicker approach without the extra properties?

Comment: @Jim I've got a .csv file with movie names and I'm writting a custom tool to pull out extra information about the movies (from omdbapi) and I'm going to use Entity Framework to throw it all in a database. The database will be consumed with ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @D6mi just a quick tip .. if u are getting Json, try [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) so u have really fast an idea about how your  response object is going to look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have two properties: one would be the string property as it comes from IMDB, and the other would be the int property that converts the string one. To convert, you can use the nifty [`NumberStyles.AllowThousands`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx) flag. So you would have

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "imdbVotes")]
public string ImdbVotes { get; set; }

public int ImdbVotesInt 
{ 
    get 
    {
        int result;
        if (int.TryParse(ImdbVotes, 
                NumberStyles.AllowThousands,
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                out result))                    
            return result;  // parse is successful, use 'result'
        else
            return 0;       // parse is unsuccessful, return whatever default value works for you       
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the unrealisticaly fast answer :). I understand what you mean, I did try to go for this solution, but I thought that a better approach would be via Custom Converters. 

I've updated my question, so I guess you'd suggest that I do the same for the other, treacherous properties?

Comment: @D6mi - I don't know about that, seems needlessly complex. Then again, I don't know your project's needs.